# How to add a class to the comment submit button?

Tags: comments, comment-form

How do I add a class to the comment submit button? The simplified function 
`comment_form(array('id_submit'=>'buttonPro'));` obviously only changes the id and `class_submit` does not seem to exist.

I have read through both [Otto's](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/) and [Beau's](http://www.slideshare.net/beaulebens/hooking-into-comments-5047868) writeups but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check out the source of the function `comment_form()`, you'll see it doesn't even print a class on the input;

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] ); ?>" />
```

I'm guessing you need to add a class for styling? Why not modify your CSS to just;

```
input.submit, #buttonPro {
    /* some awesome style */
}
```

Otherwise I guess the 'easiest' solution would be to simply copy the function to your `functions.php`, rename it, add in a class argument & print, and use that instead - which you can [find here](http://pastebin.com/PDwAbrQb) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and comment form.  :) I have a theme option that helps style the theme based on if it is a light or dark ui. If there was a simple function that could add a class I could wrap that function in an if:isdark kind of statement. I'll have to look more closely at longform function you provided.

Comment: In my Oenology Theme, I output custom CSS based on whether the current color scheme is dark or light. Here's the [`\functions\options.php` file](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/options.php) that does all of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 16):

From WordPress Version 4.1 <sup>([trac ticket #20446](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20446))</sup> it's now added to pass your own class as an argument of `comment_form($args)` using `'class_submit'` array key:

```
$args = array( 'class_submit' => 'btn btn-default' );
```

No need to do extra hard work. (Edited the Codex too) :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm working with the Foundation framework as well. I've found that the easiest way to add a class to a non-filterable element is to do it with jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //noconflict wrapper
    $('input#submit').addClass('button');
});//end noconflict
```

Comment: Never thought of that. That's hacky, but cleaner than hacking core. Copying your code right now!

Comment: I already have a heavily used jquery site. So adding this chunk of code was really easy and worked like a charm.

Comment: Just a note for future readers, its very possible that your styling will look very distorted on each page load depending on js load time, i would avoid doing this sort of class modification where possible

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a class on the submit button? You can give it an ID, as you have discovered, and that's all you need for styling it.

```
comment_form(array('id_submit'=>'buttonPro'));
```

Then to style it:

```
input#buttonPro {...}
```

Simple. Or, if you prefer to use classes only for some reason:

```
.form-submit input {...}
```

There's no advantage I can see, from any angle, to putting a class on the comment form's submit button.

Comment: Absolutely. If you need greater specificity, target your CSS selectors higher up. Look at the ID or class of the container that holds the comment reply form, or that holds the entire comments markup. Also, there should only ever be one comment reply form on any given page, so I don't see the harm in targeting the submit button ID, passed via argument, for applying CSS.

Comment: With all due respect, I disagree. I have a website+blog. I have defined a class & used it for all the buttons. Also I have different states for the buttons (normal, hover). If I were to not apply a class to the comment button, then that would mean that I have to target the blog comment button by ID and start adding the selector right next to the already defined class (comma separated). That means, I am unable to make use of already defined class & this is not preferred. Simply applying the class name to button makes life all the more easy without having me to add ID manually & keeps it simple.

Comment: Devner: You're using CSS exactly backwards from the way it is intended to be used. Class names and ID's should be semantically defined, not defined according to how you want them styled. The whole point is to be able to change the CSS instead of changing the HTML, because the HTML is often generated, while the CSS is much easier to change.

Comment: Some frameworks such as Bootstrap provide button styles on the class e.g .btn - although not a big problem, it would make things easier if a class could be added.

Comment: I know this is several years old at this point, but I'm surprised by this statement: "There's no advantage I can see, from any angle, to putting a class on the comment form's submit button." Why add an additional ID to the stylesheet when an existing class (say for button styling) can provide the styling you need?

Comment: Chris: Because HTML should be semantic. Stylesheets should be changed to change the "look" of things, while the HTML should describe the content. Changing HTML to achieve a change in the "look" is precisely what stylesheets were created to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Otto I sincerely cannot understand that your viewpoint after all these years still seems to be the same. How about Bootstrap, Foundation and other frameworks? They either use `<button>` or a "button" class. There are numerous patched that simply add a class, what is the big deal? Why does this issue seem to be held back by a few (stubborn) people, clearly spoiling it for the rest? What is the point for me having to copy over the entire file that @TheDeadMedic has been so kind to make available? Instead you guys could solve the issue by adding 2 lines in core and be done with it! Bizar!

Comment: @Otto I don't understand how I am going backwards. Apart from the reasons I specified above, I do not wish to use IDs anywhere in my stylesheet as I want to avoid specificity problems that may arise due to using them. I am trying to simply reuse my classes that I have already defined without having to do anything extra. Yes, if adding class attribute will help me not bother with specificity issues and keep my code consistent, I opt for them. Classes exist for a reason and I am speaking in favor of those reasons. Also I don't see how adding class names will make it non-semantic.

Comment: You're going backwards because you're trying to modify your HTML code to achieve a change in presentation. Altering the presentation is the job of the stylesheet and should be the thing you're trying to change here.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the same solution and at last i found the solution, the below code worked perfectly for me, I wanted to add "btn btn-primary" class to the submit button in comment form.

```
ob_start();
comment_form( $args );
$form = ob_get_clean(); 
$form = str_replace('class="comment-form"','class="comment-form"', $form);
echo str_replace('id="submit"','class="btn btn-primary"', $form);
```

the $args i used are

```
$args = array(
'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">Comment</label> <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" cols="35" rows="12" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
'fields'        => array(
    'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name <span class="required">*</span></label> <input class="form-control input-comment-author" id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required="true"></p>',
    'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">Email <span class="required">*</span></label> <input class="form-control input-comment-email" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" aria-required="true"></p>',
    'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">Website</label> <input class="form-control input-comment-url" id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="30"></p>',
),
'cancel_reply_link' => '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Cancel reply</button>',
'label_submit' => 'Post Comment',);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest those who have this problem to set a style for "post-comment" id, like what i did:

```
#post-comment {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
padding: 8px 20px;
float: left;}
```

good luck! :)

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to reply (late) since I was looking for an answer to this and decided to tackle it myself.

First, to answer the question "why add a class?"... In my case, I chose to use a UI framework called [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to design my most recent theme for my personal blog. I chose it precisely because I like its [style for buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/buttons.php). However, it requires the developer to add a class to an `<input>` button, and I didn't realize that couldn't be done in WP until I was almost completely done with the theme!

So, here's what I did. I had to edit the `/wp-includes/comment-template.php` file, so use at your own risk because it could be wiped out during a WP upgrade.

---

After line `1540` (as of version 3.2.1) add the following line:

```
'class_submit'         => 'submit',
```

Then change line `1576` to the following:

```
<input name="submit" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['class_submit'] ); ?>" type="submit" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] ); ?>" />
```

---

Now you have a new default value called `class_submit` that can be included in the `$args` array parameter on the `comment_form()` function:

```
<?php comment_form(
        array(              
            'class_submit' => __('XXX'),
        )
    ); ?>
```

Happy Wording!

Comment: it's a bad idea to hack core and on this site some people take it personally. Since you are new here, I'm going to take away your down vote that someone else left. But now you know.

Comment: Alex, Taylor is right. NEVER modify core files! NEVER EVER!

Comment: Never, modify, core files.